# EXCEL Table reference to cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make a dynamic reference to view some columns of a table. So instead of write =TABLE[aColumn] (assume that this works) I would like to have =TABLE[B2] where cell B2 contais the string "aColumn". Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: Look at `INDIRECT()`, though it's volatile so use it sparsely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT function to achieve this like this:

```
=INDIRECT("TABLE"&"["&B2&"]")
```

You can refer to the [following article](https://www.excel-university.com/indirectly-refer-to-table-columns/) for more detailed explination: